# Is there any problem of showing the api token in source? (Laravel + Vue.js)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

My situation is that I want to do api request at the front-end (using axios)
The api request requires to add the api token in the header of the request.
And I want to store the api token securely, but I have no idea how to store the api token securely.
I just figure the way below and everything works nicely.
However, I am afraid if there is any security breach by doing so.

Let say I get the api token by regenerating and stored in a variable.

in

> user-script.blade.php

```
     var vm = new Vue({
        el: "#api",
        name: "api_token",
        data: () => ({
            api_token: '{!! \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::check() ? \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->createToken('ApiToken')->accessToken : 'null' !!}',
            devices: {}
        }),
        mounted() {
            axios.get('/api/device',
                {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: "Bearer "+this.api_token
                    }
                }
            )
            .then((response) => {
                this.devices = response.data;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
        }
    })
</script>
```

However, the api_token will be shown in devtool source.
[devtool source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7jCW.png)

1. Is there any security breach if I show this to the users?
2. Is there any security breach if I store users' api token in the database?
3. Or how can I get the api token after I have already logged in?

Comment: I don't understand why you are trying to hide API token?
And by token you explicitly mean JWT?

Answer (score 0):

On the client side you cant't prevent code modification.
Any user can view your source code of all your JavaScript files.

If you care about security read material related to web vulnerabilities such as XCC, CSRF.